# Using .bat to launch a powershell script

Tags: batch-file, powershell-3.0

I can execute the following script in powershell successfully but when i try to run the script from a .bat i am unsucessful.Is there a certain way that the .bat file calls the powershell script as it keeps failing.
How would i create a .bat script to run the powershell script below.

```
cd 'Program Files (x86)\Citrix \XenApp \ServerConfig' .\XenAppConfigConsole.exe /ExecutionMode:Join /FarmName:xencity /OdbcUsername:chris /odbcPassword:Jahner0 /DsnFile:"C:\xencitylifeSQLDS.dsn"
```

Please help guys
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by putting `powershell` at the start of the command

`powershell cd 'Program Files (x86)\Citrix \XenApp \ServerConfig' .\XenAppConfigConsole.exe /ExecutionMode:Join /FarmName:xencity /OdbcUsername:chris /odbcPassword:Jahner0 /DsnFile:"C:\xencitylifeSQLDS.dsn"`

That just calls up powershell and gives it your command to run, except your running it in cmd.